# Are there any software tools to debug hardware states?

Tags: gpio, hardware

My raspberry Pi GPIO are suddenly oscillating. 
Are there software/hardware tests that can be done to do a status check of the Pi hardware

I am looking for debugging

- GPIO Status
- Hardware Faults (like Polyfuse blown, Pull up resistors not working)
- Other issues with the Pi that could be creating such issues

---

- PS : I am aware of wiringPi and the readall function

Comment: 1. Why do you think "GPIO are suddenly oscillating"? 2. What is connected to the Pi? A software tool would be about No. 10 on my debug list.

Comment: My gut reaction would be that you're likely trying to read floating inputs, which would produce semi-random results.

Comment: So, I was controlling some solenoids via a ULN2803 and the pi worked fine for several days. One day, the pi gpio started oscillating (I could see this as the solenoids would randomly rise and fall). I am taking input, but those GPIOs aren't affected. These are the output ones. What other tests can I do @Milliways? Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

To check the states try my [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html).

It may well help you track down the source.

A typical source of interference is a long unshielded wire connected to a GPIO acting as an aerial.

Comment: Will this work if the GPIO is spoilt? What are the reasons that could fry the  GPIO?

Comment: To check for broken GPIO use this [test](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Testing).  GPIO which are fried don't normally oscillate, they generally are stuck high or low.